# How to setup APScheduler in a Django project?

Tags: python, django

Specifically, how to

- Setup [APScheduler](http://pythonhosted.org/APScheduler/) in a Django project
- Start running
- Write to Django ORM

Comment: What is it you want to achieve? What do you mean by *Write to Django ORM*?

Comment: we can give you a response as clear as your question: install django, install APScheduler. write your views. use add_date_job to add a job. and do your stuff wherever you want in this jobs

Comment: Since APScheduler supports SQLAlchemy and MongoDb as job stores, he wants to use Django ORM. My guess.

Answer (score 24):

Well, I'll have a go. Assuming you have installed apscheduler (or put it in your Python path) The [basic documentation for APS](http://pythonhosted.org/APScheduler/) lists the following code for starting up a job:

```
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler

sched = Scheduler()

@sched.interval_schedule(hours=3)
def some_job():
    print "Decorated job"

sched.configure(options_from_ini_file)
sched.start()
```

The issue I suspect your having is how to trigger the startup of that in Django. You have multiple options, mostly consisting of "putting it somewhere it will be run". For example, add it to the bottom of a `models.py` file, or in `urls.py` and it will be processed once on each Django restart, then continue to run in the background. Database accesses can then be performed as normal from within the function - just import your models as normal for your queries.

However, consider that if you do this you're going to need to kill & restart your server any time you want to alter the scheduling. I'm also unsure how this is going to fare with multiple threads (will you have >1 timer?)

You really might want to consider going with something like [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) (via [django-celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/)) which gets you all this, plus a separate scheduling daemon with finer control of scheduling.

Comment: Thanks, the startup was the most interesting point for me. I was looking at APScheduler because the CrontabScheduler in Celery doesn't support resolutions smaller than minutes, and the IntervalScheduler doesn't support start_date like APScheduler does.

This means it's not possible out of the box to do things like "every second monday" and "monday at 20:14:50". But I decided to stick with Celery, and use a custom Scheduler.

I prefer to have a separate process, that runs outside of the webserver process. Much easier to control and debug, IMO.

Comment: "However, consider that if you do this you're going to need to kill & restart your server any time you want to alter the scheduling." Actually this won't necessarily require killing the server. Simply starting APscheduler doesn't require it to have jobs added. OP could simply start the scheduler in some place and then have code elsewhere to add and remove jobs as needed, in a view for certain users, for instance. If OP doesn't want to deal with the overhead of using Celery and plans on keeping things simple, this is still an option.

Comment: If you were deploying on Heroku, could you create a `clock.py` file and call it from your Procfile? (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/clock-processes-python)[https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/clock-processes-python]

Answer (score 7):

To use this apscheduler,  you can set it up with the code below, the only part you may be having difficulties with is using the jobstore `sqlalchemy` is recommended but since you already have a django ORM, that can work also.

```
   from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

   scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
   scheduler.start()

  def myjob():
     print('hello')


  scheduler.add_job(myjob, 'cron', hour=0)
  scheduler.add_job(
     myjob,
     'date',
     id=id_value,
     jobstore="default",
     run_date=scheduler_date,
     replace_existing=True
  )
```

I would recommend using : [django-apscheduler](https://github.com/jarekwg/django-apscheduler) which already integrate with jobstore with DjangoORM and also provides a web interface to manage jobs

For django-apscheduler, you can use the code below

```
import time

from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from django_apscheduler.jobstores import DjangoJobStore, register_events, 
register_job

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.add_jobstore(DjangoJobStore(), "default")

@register_job(scheduler, "interval", seconds=1)
def test_job():
    time.sleep(4)
    print("I'm a test job!")
    # raise ValueError("Olala!")

register_events(scheduler)

scheduler.start()
print("Scheduler started!")
```

Answer (score 4):

just try below code.

`project name`: `crawling_server`

```sh
django-admin startproject crawling_server
cd crawling_server
```

`app name` : `stock_crawling`

```
python manage.py startapp stock_crawling
```

`purpose` : print 'hello world' every second

### 1. install packages

```sh
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

```
APScheduler==3.8.1
asgiref==3.4.1
backports.zoneinfo==0.2.1
beautifulsoup4==4.10.0
certifi==2021.10.8
Django==3.2.10
django-apscheduler==0.6.0
pytz==2021.3
pytz-deprecation-shim==0.1.0.post0
six==1.16.0
soupsieve==2.3.1
sqlparse==0.4.2
typing_extensions==4.0.1
tzdata==2021.5
tzlocal==4.1
```

### 2.

add below code at `settings.py`

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ... 
    'stock_crawling',
    'django_apscheduler',
]

APSCHEDULER_DATETIME_FORMAT = "N j, Y, f:s a"  # Default

SCHEDULER_DEFAULT = True
```

### 3.

add below code at `views.py`

```py
import datetime


def send_hello():
    time = datetime.datetime.now()
    print('hello world:[{}]'.format(time))
```

### 4

generate `operator.py` in project dir (see below dir tree)

```
./
├── crawling_server <- **project dir** 
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── operator.py <- **generate this script** 
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── requirements.txt
└── stock_crawling 
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── migrations
    ├── models.py
    ├── tests.py
    └── views.py
```

add below code at `operator.py`

```py
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from django_apscheduler.jobstores import register_events, DjangoJobStore
from stock_crawling.views import send_hello


def start():
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_jobstore(DjangoJobStore(), 'djangojobstore')
    register_events(scheduler)

    @scheduler.scheduled_job('interval', seconds=1, name='auto_hello')
    def auto_hello():
        send_hello()

    scheduler.start()
```

Either [interval](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/modules/triggers/interval.html)  or [cron](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/modules/triggers/cron.html) is used as the scheduler trigger. For more information, see the link below.

example **interval** trigger

```py
@scheduler.scheduled_job('interval', seconds=1, name='auto_hello')
```

example **cron** trigger

```py
@scheduler.scheduled_job('cron', hour=1, name='auto_hello')
```

### 5.

add below code at `app.py` in project dir

```py
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.conf import settings


class StockCrawlingConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'stock_crawling'

    def ready(self):
        if settings.SCHEDULER_DEFAULT:
            from crawling_server import operator
            operator.start()
```

### 6. runserver

```sh
python manage.py runserver --noreload
```

## 7. result

```
hello world:[2021-12-13 12:34:33.982562]
Job '259a33f9664248bea607aa9ba0cdd587' no longer exists! Skipping logging of job execution...
Job '259a33f9664248bea607aa9ba0cdd587' no longer exists! Skipping logging of job execution...
hello world:[2021-12-13 12:34:34.982743]
Job '259a33f9664248bea607aa9ba0cdd587' no longer exists! Skipping logging of job execution...
Job '259a33f9664248bea607aa9ba0cdd587' no longer exists! Skipping logging of job execution...
hello world:[2021-12-13 12:34:35.986722]
```