# Django background tasks

Tags: django

I have an industrial controls system that I would like integrate into a simple django project. I'd like django to fetch values and commit this data without user interaction. Is there a simple way to have fields populated in this fashion on timed intervals? . For now I have temperature data from one sensor that I would like to fetch every 30 seconds so FloatField and a timestamp for that field.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your questions is pretty much the same as the answer to [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654353/how-to-setup-apscheduler-in-a-django-project) question. You could use [APScheduler](http://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)'s [add_job](http://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/schedulers/base.html#apscheduler.schedulers.base.BaseScheduler.add_job) or [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/)'s [periodic tasks](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) to run tasks/jobs every 30 seconds.

Celery might be more reliable, but it's just my gut feeling.

Oh, and it supports Django [out of the box](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) (there's also the older [django-celery package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery)).